# JavaScript Scopes inside inline event handlers

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to execute a function which is dynamically fetched, but I am getting an undefined error. I think it probably has something to do with scope but I don't know the exact problem.

This is code.

```
<button onmouseover="function load_script(){import('/script.js')};load_script()" onclick="checker()">Click
```

The script file is located at root and has these contents.

```
export const checker = () => console.log(2020);
```

The browser does fetch the script upon mousehover but it cannot find the function `checker` on click event which makes me think this problem is related to scope but I can't resolve it.

Any ideas?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539045 - best solution, remove all inline event handlers and attach them properly using JavaScript instead

Comment: @CertainPerformance That question is 12 years old, a lot has changed since then. The answer you referred does not mention how do scopes work with let, const and ES6 modules. I am using dynamic imports which didn't even back then.

Comment: The answer is from the end of 2019 / beginning of 2020. It explains the scope of inline handlers, and explains the scope of ES6 modules, and looks to adequately cover what you're running into here.